# Need to check if user is on a particular page

Tags: urls

Here I hope is a simple question for a php newbie.  I have a textbox on my blog's home page that contains a link to another page.  Should the visitor click the link and go to that page, I want to be able to check to see if the user is there so I can change the text and CSS.

I know how to use the ishome() function, but what function do I use to check if the user is on the page in question? It's not a post, just the mysite.com/what-we-do page.

Thanks.

Comment: Not I've understood, but maybe you need [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

Comment: If you want to change something depending if a user is logged in you could use the `is_user_logged_in_()` [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

Comment: Yes, I did use is_page and that worked like a tee.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not a post, just the mysite.com/what-we-do page.

Refer to [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page).

```
<?php
if ( is_page( 'what-we-do' ) ) {
    // We're on the What We Do page
    // do something
}
?>
```

Comment: And is there a way to go back to the referring page?